# Problem loading WAR properties file as a module in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have a working application running in JBoss EAP 7.3, with some properties files. I'm trying to move these files to modules, as explained here:

https://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-configuration/how-to-inject-system-properties-into-jboss/

When deploying the application I'm getting this error

```
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add resource root './connector.properties' at path './connector.properties' (position: END_TAG seen ...<resources>\r\n    <resource-root path="./connector.properties"/>... @4:51) caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
```

Apparently JBoss is expecting a jar or zip file, how can I get it to load the properties files?

this is the module.xml content, this and the properties files are located in \modules\system\layers\base\com\connector\main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.connector">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="./connector.properties"/>
    <resource-root path="./connector-web.properties"/>
    <resource-root path="./pge-client.properties"/>
  </resources>
</module>
```

this is in my standalone.xml file

```
<global-modules>
     <module name="com.connector" slot="main"/>
</global-modules>
```

Thanks